# How to create new error without a stack trace?

Tags: go, error-handling

I create an error from `github.com/pkg/errors` by calling:

```
err = errors.New(fmt.Sprintf(...))
```

By default, it's populated with a stack trace. I would like to create an `error` but with a message only.

Is it possible?

Comment: `errors.New` from the std lib doesn't add a stack trace. What lib are you using? or are you passing that error directly to `panic`? Perhaps you're using this https://github.com/pkg/errors? If so, use the standard [`"errors"`](https://golang.org/pkg/errors/) package for your no-stacktrace-errors.

Comment: There's never any reason to do `errors.New(fmt.Sprintf(...))`.  Just use `errors.Errorf` instead (or for the standard library, `fmt.Errorf`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the [github.com/pkg/errors](https://godoc.org/github.com/pkg/errors) package which does some neat things like adding stack traces.

But this is an external package. The [errors](https://golang.org/pkg/errors/) packages from the standard library does not include stack traces.

You can use it as follows:

```
import "errors"

err := errors.New("my error message")
```

Or with formatting, use the [fmt](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) package:

```
import "fmt"

err := fmt.Errorf("I have %d bugs", 10)
```

Answer (score 2):

`github.com/pkg/errors` will always store your error stack traces info, but it's your free to choose the format you want to show:

```golang
err := errors.New("test")
fmt.Printf("%v", err)  // show only message
fmt.Printf("%+v", err) // show message with full stack info
```

This lib impelmented the `fmt.Formatter` interface to change the output behavior:

```golang
func (f *fundamental) Format(s fmt.State, verb rune) {
    switch verb {
    case 'v':
        if s.Flag('+') {
            io.WriteString(s, f.msg)
            f.stack.Format(s, verb)
            return
        }
        fallthrough
    case 's':
        io.WriteString(s, f.msg)
    case 'q':
        fmt.Fprintf(s, "%q", f.msg)
    }
}
```

Here is the whole source code: https://github.com/pkg/errors/blob/master/errors.go

Answer (score 1):

`github.com/pkg/errors` has been deprecated and I made [its spiritual successor](https://gitlab.com/tozd/go/errors) named `gitlab.com/tozd/go/errors` some time ago [which addresses a long list of issues](https://gitlab.com/tozd/go/errors#why-a-new-go-errors-package) `github.com/pkg/errors` has. It was also not updated to support a newer Go handling pattern: sentinel errors. Sentinel errors is where you define constant errors at the top-level of your packages, exported, so that you can use `errors.Is` and `errors.As` to check what the error is (instead of trying to parse that from fragile error strings).

`gitlab.com/tozd/go/errors` provides for this another set of "base" functions which do not record a stack trace. Your example would then be:

```golang
import gitlab.com/tozd/go/errors

...

err = errors.Base(fmt.Sprintf(...))
```

Or even better (not need to call `fmt.Sprintf` yourself):

```golang
err = errors.Basef(...)
```

So no need to have multiple imports here (standard `errors`, and another one with stack traces). Just one import with all utility functions for your errors needs.

When the error happens in your function, you can then annotate the base error with a stack trace like so:

```golang
func DoSomething() error {
    // Oh noooo.
    return errors.WithStack(err)
}
```